# How to upload images and keep track of them using a database using multer or busboy?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, busboy

I am trying to upload images or pdfs (files in general) using express and the two modules i have come across are multer and busboy. The image uploading process is easy however i have come across problems with both of them. What i want is to upload the image with a name that I can later plug into a database too so that when i want to retrieve the file i can simply put the name of the file in the img tag and be done with it. In Busboy req.body for some reason is empty so I cannot pass anymore information using a form such as the username of the person. In multer we cannot customly name it we have to specify the filename inside the initial setup of multer. What i want is to have a form which enables us to enter a username and a file. Then i can using that username generate a random string which can be the same for both the file and the entry i will make into the database so that I can easily grab it later. Both the busboy and multer setup and usage is given below:

busboy setup:

```
router.post('/profileUpload', function(req,res){
let username = 'dual'
let busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  let saveTo = './public/profileimage/'+`${username}.jpg`;
  console.log('Uploading: ' + saveTo);
  file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
});
busboy.on('finish', function() {
  console.log('Upload complete');
});
return req.pipe(busboy);
```

})

Multer setup:

```
const multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: './public/reports',
filename: function (req, file, cb){
cb(null,'report' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
}
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
router.post('/reportUpload',upload.single('doc'),function(req,res){
let usernameLab = req.session.usernameLab
let username = req.body.patientUsername 
var d = new Date()
var uniqstring = Date.now()
let uniqname = 'report' + uniqstring
var date = `${d.getFullYear()}/${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}` 
let testName = req.body.testName
let department = req.body.department
let params = [username, usernameLab, uniqname, date, testName, department]
let promise = queries.reportUpload(params)
promise.then(function(){
    res.redirect('/reportUpload?upload=success')
    })
});
```

Comment: I really confused about the question, but in multer `req.file` will contain the file information, including the name.